# What do I need to be aware of if I'm considering purchasing a Personal Locator Beacon (PLB)?

Tags: gear, rescue, personal-locator-beacons

Obviously, I can't just buy it, push the button and expect a helicopter to show up.

Are there monthly or registration fees? Do I need to get a permit or register with someone? How does it all work? Does it get service everywhere (even internationally)? I'm not even sure what I don't know at this point.

Basically, if you were telling a friend how to purchase a PLB, what would you tell them?

Comment: Which country? I don't think they're allowed inland in the UK

Comment: Good point, the United States.

Comment: Ofcom have recently added an exemption which does now allow PLBs to be used in the UK.  See http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/binaries/consultations/licence-exemption/statement/statement.pdf

Comment: See also [*Are PLBs banned or otherwise useless anywhere?*](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3307/566*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia article has a lot of detail: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distress_radiobeacon.

There's no fee. In the USA, the response comes from government agencies such as the Coast Guard.

It does need to be registered, but registration is [free and easy online](http://www.beaconregistration.noaa.gov/).

If you use it when there's not an emergency, you could be fined.