# Are PLBs banned or otherwise useless anywhere?

Tags: legality, personal-locator-beacons

[This comment](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/724/what-do-i-need-to-be-aware-of-if-im-considering-purchasing-a-personal-locator-b#comment785_724) raises the idea that PLBs may not be allowed inland in the UK. [A later comment](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/724/what-do-i-need-to-be-aware-of-if-im-considering-purchasing-a-personal-locator-b#comment799_724) refuted this, but I never even considered they would be disallowed anywhere, but simply rented one and took it with me on a hike in Norway and Sweden (fortunately I didn't use it).

- Are Personal Locator Beacons banned anywhere in the world?
- Are Personal Locator Beacons useless in some countries, e.g. because nobody will come anyway? Where could I find information about this?

Answer (score 10):

According to [this article on Walk Highlands, from December 2011](http://www.walkhighlands.co.uk/news/personal-locator-beacons-legalised-for-hillwalkers/006043/):

> Hillwalkers and climbers will be able to legally carry Personal
>   Locator Beacons (PLBs) from 12 January following a change in UK
>   regulations. Previously the devices, which send out a distress signal
>   identifying the user’s exact location when activated, could only be
>   licensed for use on boats and planes.

After a bit of further rummaging, the [relevant OFCOM document is here](http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/binaries/spectrum/spectrum-policy-area/spectrum-management/research-guidelines-tech-info/interface-requirements/IR_2084_PLB.pdf)

But to specifically answer the question, certainly within the EU, you should be OK (given the OFCOM change came about from an EU directive) and there is an EU-wide SAR system.

Further afield, you'll have to check if you go there...